# Geological maps of British Columbia

Tags: geology, mineralogy, mapping, mining, resources

I’ve been doing research into mineral deposits in B.C. I’ve been overlaying old claims maps onto Google Earth maps. Are there any good public maps for metallic minerals for British Columbia online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web site "Map Place" has a number of maps if you have internet explorer and can download an autodesk plugin.  [Table of Maps from Map Place](http://www.empr.gov.bc.ca/Mining/Geoscience/MapPlace/Pages/default.aspx)

I have used this site to find locations with limestone bedrock but also to find old claims to look for areas with unique mineral samples.  I will caution you that the old claims in particular are not very accurately mapped.  A lot of the initial locations are based on hip chain and hand compass surveying, or even worst based on a location pointed out on a topographic map.  There has been little work to ground proof the old locations.  Some of the locations can be 500 meters or more out which doesn't seem like much, that is until you end up in dense forest looking over a 70 hectare area for an audit or cut.  Data collected since about 1994 and later started to be based on GPS ground measurements and are more accurate.  The majority of data now collect is based on tighter location data.  You may also find some issues with the datum used.  A lot of older data is based from NAD27, but the transition to NAD83 and WGS84 was over a time period and the data collected during the transition time wasn't always recorded with the datum information.

Obviously the accuracy issue will depend on how you plan to used the data, it is likely ok for displaying zones of interest on a map.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a geologic map this [site](https://opentextbc.ca/geography/chapter/5-3-british-columbias-natural-resources/) has a nice map of mines for silver, gold, copper, molybdenum, and zinc.  Below is a screenshot of just a portion of the pdf you can download.

[image]